# Using vim for comparing files

Tags: command-line, vim

I try to use vim to compare two files `file1.txt` and `file2.txt` via the command line (cmd) on Windows7 by calling `vim -d file1.txt file2.txt`

I get the error:

```
C:\Programming\R>vim -d file1.txt file2.txt
2 files to edit
"\Vim\vim74\diff" -a --binary C:\Users\JOHNMO~1\AppData\Local\Temp\VIo2B6B.tmp C
:\Users\JOHNMO~1\AppData\Local\Temp\VIn2B6C.tmp > C:\Users\CHRIST~1\AppData\Loca
l\Temp\VId2B6D.tmp")" kann syntaktisch an dieser Stelle nicht verarbeitet werden
.
```

Then

```
E810: Cannot read or write temp files
E97: Cannot create diffs
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

What can I do to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The key to solving that probably lies in one of the `'shell'`, `'shellquote'`, `'shellxquote'`, and `'shellcmdflag'` options. Do you have set any non-default values?! The defaults for Windows have changed around Vim 7.3.443, so if you've previously used plain 7.3 and now have upgraded to Vim 7.4, that may be the reason.

Comment: Yes, I did update vim to 7.4 from a version I installed 4 year ago. Are you saying that I basically have to get the fresh _vimrc of Vim 7.4 or are you saying something different?

Comment: Do you have customized any of those `shell...` settings? If yes, it's a good idea to revert them to their (new) defaults. If not (if that's the case, `vim -N -u NONE -d file1.txt file2.txt` should also give you the error), something in your system doesn't like the new quoting of Vim 7.4.